# Datatype of Methods

Tags: c#, function, methods, types

## Question

How does a delegate store a reference to a function?  The source code appears to refer to it as an Object, and the manner in which it invokes the method seems redacted from the source code.  Can anyone explain how C# is handling this?

---

## Original Post

It seems I'm constantly fighting the abstractions C# imposes on its programmers.  One that's been irking me is the obfuscation of Functions/Methods.  As I understand it, all methods are in fact anonymous methods assigned to properties of a class. This is the reason why no function is prefixed by a datatype.  For example...

```
void foo() { ... }
```

... would be written in Javascript as...

```
Function foo = function():void { ... };
```

In my experience, Anonymous functions are typically bad form, but here it's replete throughout the language standard.  Because you cannot define a function with its datatype (and apparently the implication/handling is assumed by the compiler), **how does one store a reference to a method** if the type is never declared?

I'm trying very hard to avoid [`Delegates`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=netframework-4.7.2) and its variants ([`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.7.2) & [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)), both because...

1. it is another abstraction from what's actually happening
2. the unnecessary overhead required to instantiate these classes (which in turn carry their own pointers to the methods being called).

Looking at the [source code for the `Delegate.cs`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/delegate.cs), it appears to refer to the reference of a function as simply `Object` (see lines 23-25).

---

If these really are objects, how are we calling them?  According to the `delegate.cs` trail, it dead-ends on the following path:

`Delegate.cs:DynamicInvoke()` > `DynamicInvokeImpl()` > `methodinfo.cs:UnsafeInvoke()` > `UnsafeInvokeInternal()` > `RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod()` > `runtimehandles.cs:InvokeMethod()`

```
internal extern static object InvokeMethod(object target, object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor);
```

This really doesn't explain how its invoked if indeed the method is an object.  It feels as though this is not code at all, and the actual code called has been redacted from source repository.

Your help is appreciated.

---

### Response to Previous Comments

*@Amy:* I gave an example immediately after that statement to explain what I meant.  If a function were prefixed by a datatype, you could write a true anonymous function, and store it as a property to an Object such as:

```
private Dictionary<string, Function> ops = new Dictionary<string, Function> {
    {"foo", int (int a, int b) { return a + b } }
};
```

As it stands, C# doesn't allow you to write true anonymous functions, and walls that functionality off behind [`Delegates`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods) and [`Lambda expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).

*@500 Internal server error:* I already explained what I was trying to do.  I even bolded it.  You assume there's any ulterior motive here; I'm simply trying to understand how C# stores a reference to a method.  I even provided links to the source code so that others could read the code for themselves and help answer the question.

*@Dialecticus:* Obviously if I already found the typical answer on Google, the only other place to find the answer I'm looking for would be here.  I realize this is outside the knowledge of most C# developers, and that's why I've provided the source code links.  You don't have to reply if you don't know the answer.

Comment: `all methods are in fact anonymous methods assigned to properties of a class`  This statement is simply not correct regarding C#.

Comment: `I'm constantly fighting the abstractions` - perhaps if you explained what you're trying to do...

Comment: `why no function is prefixed by a datatype`  I'm not sure what you're talking about.  Every function is declared on a class or struct in C#.

Comment: If you google for your bolded text you get the answer. But then you reject that solution. At this point it's difficult to help you. Maybe someone can explain why your reasons to reject the solution are wrong. But for this to happen you should ask another question...

Comment: I think the whole point of using a higher level language is to leverage abstractions for faster (and safer) coding at a minor performance expense. You mention you stay away from delegates because "it is another abstraction" and because of the "unnecessary overhead". the overhead **IS** a result of the abstractions. If you prefer less overhead and less abstractions, try a lower level language, like C++.

Comment: In .NET, all methods have a fixed return type. It is not necessarily visible in the C# source because it might be inferred. Delegates use runtime magic to call functions. Normal function calls use IL call instructions.; A delegate is a way to reference a method. You can definitely store delegates anywhere such as in a dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I'm not fully understanding your insights about "true anonymous functions", "not prefixed by a data type" etc, I can explain you how applications written in C# call methods.

First of all, there is no such a thing "function" in C#. Each and every executable entity in C# is in fact a method, that means, it belongs to a `class`. Even if you define lambdas or anonymous functions like this:

```
collection.Where(item => item > 0);
```

the C# compiler creates a *compiler-generated* class behind the scenes and puts the lambda body `return item > 0` into a *compiler-generated* method.

So assuming you have this code:

```
class Example
{
    public static void StaticMethod() { }
    public void InstanceMethod() { }
    public Action Property { get; } = () => { };
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Example.StaticMethod();
        var ex = new Example();
        ex.InstanceMethod();
        ex.Property();
    }
}
```

The C# compiler will create an IL code out of that. The IL code is not executable right away, it needs to be run in a virtual machine.

The IL code will contain a class `Example` with two methods (actually, four - a default constructor and the property getter method will be automatically generated) and a *compiler-generated* class containing a method whose body is the body of the lambda expression.

The IL code of `Main` will look like this (simplified):

```
call void Example::StaticMethod()
newobj instance void Example::.ctor()
callvirt instance void Example::InstanceMethod()
callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Action Example::get_Prop()
callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.Action::Invoke()
```

Notice those `call` and `callvirt` instructions: these are method calls.

To actually execute the called methods, their IL code needs to be compiled into machine code (CPU instructions). This occurs in the virtual machine called .NET Runtime. There are several of them like .NET Framework, .NET Core, Mono etc.

A .NET Runtime contains a JIT (just-in-time) compiler. It converts the IL code to the actually executable code *during the execution of your program*.

When the .NET Runtime first encounters the IL code "call method `StaticMethod` from class `Example`", it first looks in the internal cache of already compiled methods. When there are no matches (which means this is the first call of that method), the Runtime asks the JIT compiler to create such a compiled-and-ready-to-run method using the IL code. The IL code is converted into a sequence of CPU operations and stored in the process' memory. A pointer to that compiled code is stored in the cache for future reuse.

This all will happen behind the `call` or `callvirt` IL instructions (again, simplified).

Once this happened, the Runtime is ready to execute the method. The CPU gets the compiled code's first operation address as the next operation to execute and goes on until the code returns. Then, the Runtime takes over again and proceeds with next IL instructions.

The `DynamicInvoke` method of the delegates does the same thing: it instructs the Runtime to call a method (after some additional arguments checks etc). The "dead end" you mention `RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod` is an intrinsic call to the Runtime directly. The parameters of this method are:

- `object target` - the object on which the delegate invokes the instance method (`this` parameter).
- `object[] arguments` - the arguments to pass to the method.
- `Signature sig` - the actual method to call, `Signature` is an internal class that provides the connection between the managed IL code and native executable code.
- `bool constructor` - `true` if this is a constructor call.

So in summary, methods are not represented as `object`s in C# (while you of course can have a `delegate` instance that *is* an `object`, but it doesn't represent the *executable* method, it rather *provides an invokable reference* to it).

Methods are called by the Runtime, the JIT compiler makes the methods executable.

You cannot define a global "function" outside of classes in C#. You *could* get a direct native pointer to the compiled (jitted) method code and probably even call it manually by directly manipulating own process' memory. But why?

Comment: I dispute your claim that "there is no such a thing function in C#".  A function is defined as a method with a return type other than void, or in the case of lambdas, any code executed,including expressions, that returns a value.  What should be expressed is the fact, true polymorphism is not available in C#, by design, due to the strong typing system. We have Interfaces to supplant that roll, but being strongly typed, they, do not equate to the OPs requirements of a "function".  I do not dispute that every function/method must be enclosed in a class.

Comment: @Strom, in OOP, a method is a function associated with a class. A method is a member function. In C#, it's impossible to have a function outside of classes, so therefore there are no bare functions in C# - they all are member functions or methods.

Answer (score 4):

You clearly misunderstand main differences between script languages, C/C++ and C#.

I guess the main difficulty is that there is **no such thing as a function in C#**. At all. 
C#7 introduced the new feature "a local function", but that is not what a function in JS is.
All pieces of code are *methods*. 
That name is intentionally different from *function* or a *procedure* to emphasize the fact that all executable code in C# belongs to a class.

Anonymous methods and lambdas are just a syntax sugar.
A compiler will generate a real method in the same (or a nested) class, where the method with anonymous method declaration belongs to.

This [simple article](https://adnanboz.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/under-the-anonymous-methods-in-c/) explains it. You can take the examples, compile them and check the generated IL code yourself.

So **all the methods (anonymous or not) do belong to a class.** It's impossible to answer your updated question, besides saying *It does not store a reference to a function, as there is no such thing in C#*.

> How does one store a reference to a method?

Depending on what you mean by reference, it can be either

1. An instance of [MethodInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) class, used to reference reflection information for a method,
2. [RuntimeMethodHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtimemethodhandle?view=netframework-4.7.2) (obtainable via RuntimeMethodInfo.MethodHandle) stores a real memory pointer to a JITed method code
3. A delegate, that is *very different* from just a memory pointer, but logically could be used to "pass a method reference to another method" .

I believe you are looking for the *MethodInfo* option, it has a [MethodInfo.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke?view=netframework-1.1) method which is very much alike [Function..apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function in JS. You have already seen in the Delegate source code how that class is used.

If by "reference" you mean the C-style function pointer, it is in [RuntimeMethodHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtimemethodhandle?view=netframework-4.7.2) struct. You should never use it without solid understanding how a particular .Net platform implementation and a C# compiler work.

Hopefully it clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

A delegate is simply a pointer(memory location to jump to) to a method with the specified parameters and return type.  Any Method that matches the signature(Parameters and return type) is eligible to fulfill the role, irrespective of the defined object. Anonymous simply means the delegate is not named.

Most times the type is implied(if it is not you will get a compiler error):
C# is a strongly typed language. That means every expression (including delegates) MUST have a return type(including void) as well as strongly typed parameters(if any). Generics were created to permit explicit types to be used within general contexts, such as Lists.

To put it another way, delegates are the type-safe managed version of C++ callbacks.

Delegates are helpful in eliminating switch statements by allowing the code to jump to the proper handler without testing any conditions.

A delegate is similar to a Closure in Javascript terminology.

In your response to Amy, you are attempting to equate a loosely typed language like JS, and a strongly typed language C#.  In C# it is not possible to pass an arbitrary(loosely-typed) function anywhere. Lambdas and delegates are the only way to guarantee type safety.

I would recommend trying F#, if you are looking to pass functions around.

**EDIT**:

If you are trying to mimic the behavior of Javascipt, I would try looking at using inheritance through Interfaces. I can mimic multiple inheritance, and be type safe at the same time.  But, be aware that it cannot fully supplant Javascript's dependency injection model.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably found out C# doesn't have the concept of a function as in your JavaScript example.

C# is a statically typed language and the only way you can use function pointers is by using  the built in types (Func,Action) or custom delegates.(I'm talking about safe,strongly typed pointers)
Javascript is a dynamic language that's why you can do what you describe

If you are willing to lose type safety, you can use the "dynamic" features of C# or refection to achieve what you want like in the following examples **(Don't do this,use Func/Action)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>> FuncOps = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>>
        {
            {"add", (a, b) => a + b},
            {"subtract", (a, b) => a - b}
        };

        //There are no anonymous delegates
        //private static Dictionary<string, delegate> DelecateOps = new Dictionary<string, delegate>
        //{
        //    {"add", delegate {} }
        //};

        private static Dictionary<string, dynamic> DynamicOps = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
        {
            {"add", new Func<int, int, int>((a, b) => a + b)},
            {"subtract", new Func<int, int, int>((a, b) => a - b)},
            {"inverse", new Func<int,  int>((a) => -a )} //Can't do this with Func
        };

        private static Dictionary<string, MethodInfo> ReflectionOps = new Dictionary<string, MethodInfo>
        {
            {"abs", typeof(Math).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "Abs" && m.ReturnParameter.ParameterType == typeof(int))}
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(FuncOps["add"](3, 2));//5
            Console.WriteLine(FuncOps["subtract"](3, 2));//1

            Console.WriteLine(DynamicOps["add"](3, 2));//5
            Console.WriteLine(DynamicOps["subtract"](3, 2));//1
            Console.WriteLine(DynamicOps["inverse"](3));//-3

            Console.WriteLine(ReflectionOps["abs"].Invoke(null, new object[] { -1 }));//1
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

one more example that you shouldn't use

```
delegate object CustomFunc(params object[] paramaters);
private static Dictionary<string, CustomFunc> CustomParamsOps = new Dictionary<string, CustomFunc>
{
    {"add", parameters => (int) parameters[0] + (int) parameters[1]},
    {"subtract", parameters => (int) parameters[0] - (int) parameters[1]},
    {"inverse", parameters => -((int) parameters[0])}
};

Console.WriteLine(CustomParamsOps["add"](3, 2)); //5
Console.WriteLine(CustomParamsOps["subtract"](3, 2)); //1
Console.WriteLine(CustomParamsOps["inverse"](3)); //-3
```

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a really short and simplified answer compared to the others. Everything in C# (classes, variables, properties, structs, etc) has a backed with tons of things your programs can hook into. This network of backend stuff slightly lowers the speed of C# when compared to "deeper" languages like C++, but also gives programmers a lot more tools to work with and makes the language easier to use. In this backend is included things like "garbage collection," which is a feature that automatically deletes objects from memory when there are no variables left that reference them. Speaking of reference, the whole system of passing objects by reference, which is default in C#, is also managed in the backend. In C#, Delegates are possible because of features in this backend that allow for something called "reflection."

From Wikipedia:

> Reflection is the ability of a computer program to examine,
>   introspect, and modify its own structure and behavior at runtime.

So when C# compiles and it finds a Delegate, it is just going to make a function, and then store a reflective reference to that function in the variable, allowing you to pass it around and do all sorts of cool stuff with it. You aren't actually storing the function itself in the variable though, you are storing a reference, which is kinda like an address that points you to where the function is stored in RAM.

Comment: I applaud your attempt at a simplified answer, but, Delegates do not use Reflection.  They are assigned by address dynamically through the run-time.  This differs from a call to Reflection, since the address is available to the run-time as opposed to looking it up within the assembly.